# Sending a client certificate to a SOAP server using Soap::Lite

Tags: perl, soap, certificate

I have a .p12 certificate file (PKCS#12), which I've convert to PEM format and I'm trying to send it to the server to prove I yam what I yam. I'm using SOAP::Lite. The support folks at the service I'm trying to access say the certificate isn't being sent. Can you pinpoint what I might be doing wrong?

We've been able to succeed using a powershell script, but only by sending the .p12 file and a password, so I'm not sure whether the issue is the certificate format or the way I'm trying to send it.  Here's the program (service, passwords and stuff munged for security).
So **question #2** is, are there any options for sending a .p12 formatted x509 cert and password?

Thanks in advance!

```
use strict vars;
use strict subs;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use SOAP::Lite 'trace', 'debug';
use XML::Twig;
use XML::LibXML;

$ENV{PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME} = 0;
my $proxy = "https://wxyzervices.service.com/los/webservice/AuthService.asmx";
my $uri = "http://www.thing.com/los/wxyzervices/";

my $soap = SOAP::Lite
            -> proxy($proxy, ssl_opts=> {
                 SSL_cert_file => '/scripts/data/lqbcert/mydata.pem',
                 SSL_key_file => '/scripts/data/lqbcert/mydata.key.pem',
                }
            );
$soap->default_ns($uri);

# Tricky stuff necessary for working with .NET SOAP server.

$soap->on_action( sub { sprintf '%s%s', @_});


my $ticket = $soap->call(
    SOAP::Data->name('GetUserAuthTicket')->attr({xmlns => $uri}),
    SOAP::Data->name('userName')->value('MyName')->type(''),
    SOAP::Data->name('passWord')->value('MyPassword')->type(''));

if ($ticket->fault)
{
    print "\nERROR:\n";
    print join(', ', ($ticket->faultcode, $ticket->faultstring, $ticket->faultdetail));
}

else
{
    print "Ok? \n";
    Dumper($ticket);
}
```

Comment: Re "*`$ENV{PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME} = 0;`*", It kinda defies the point to use encrypted communication if you'll talk to anyone. ("Howdy! Can you show me some id? ...On second though, nevermind. I'm going to assume you're the person to whom I want to speak. But let's make sure that noone else hears us, ok stranger?")

Comment: If .p12 means PKCS#12, then it should work: "The certificate can be given as a file with SSL_cert_file or as an internal representation of an X509* object (like you get from Net::SSLeay or IO::Socket::SSL::Utils::PEM_xxx2cert) with SSL_cert. If given as a file it will automatically detect the format. Supported file formats are PEM, DER and PKCS#12, where PEM and PKCS#12 can contain the certificate and the chain to use, while DER can only contain a single certificate."

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  I'll enable the server cert. once I figure this out. One issue at a time. Do you have any idea why my certificate as shown above isn't being sent? (I did mean PKCS#12).